# Cannot delete Linux traffic control qdisc using its handle

Tags: trafficshaping

I am a beginner with Linux TC. I cannot figure out why a certain **qdisc** which I added to the root of an interface cannot be deleted by specifying its **handle**.

Yes, I know I can delete it using the `root` specifier if it's attached to the *root* of the interface, but I should also be able to **delete** it by **handle**.

```
root@pc:/home/pc# tc qdisc add dev enp0s3 root netem
root@pc:/home/pc# tc qdisc show
qdisc noqueue 0: dev lo root refcnt 2
qdisc netem 8005: dev enp0s3 root refcnt 2 limit 1000
root@pc:/home/pc# tc qdisc delete dev enp0s3 handle 8005
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
root@pc:/home/pc# tc qdisc delete dev enp0s3 root
root@pc:/home/pc#
```

In the above sample, a `netem` **qdisc** was added, and it's handle is shown as 8005. I try to delete it by specifying that handle. This doesn't work. But obviously, specifying `root` as the handle works.

Why?